# WPF Data Binding - Get value from parent

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, binding

I have the following .xaml:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding EntityInstanceGroupings}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding EntityInstances}">
                <TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}" />
                            <Button Content="Add" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                                ...
                            </Button>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    ...
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

At the line:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}" />
```

I'm trying to bind to a property "GroupName" that is in the EntityInstanceGroupings view model.  I can't figure out to do this (if it is even possible).  Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using `RelativeSource`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem},
    Path=DataContext.GroupName}" />
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I needed.  I was missing the "DataContext" part of the path when I attempted to use RelativeSource.

Answer (score 0):

If I can follow your logic, your `TreeView` is gets a list of **EntityInstance group**. The `TreeView`s rootNodes are these groups. In the `TreeView.ItemTemplate` you want to show the name of each group.

In this case the `DataContext` of the `TreeViewItem` and the `TextBox` too should be a **group of EntityInstances**.

Which means that you just set the `Binding` to the prop directly:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

While what I was trying to do was achieved, I did find a better solution to achieve what I wanted.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="entityTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LayoutName}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="groupingTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding EntityInstances}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource entityTemplate}">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content="Add" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                ...
            </Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>    
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- Instantiate the TreeView control -->
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding EntityInstanceGroupings}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource groupingTemplate}" />
```